# optimization with non smooth constraint

Tags: optimization

I am trying to maximize the profit of a power plant. I have a constraint which is that the power plant, when operating, has a minimum and maximum capacity. (So a power block either has an output of zero or between min-max capacity). I am considering how to go about formulating this constraint. I considered some sort of step function, but this would make the constraint non smooth and thus not solvable with regular solvers? 
Is there some other way to write this function?

Many thanks

Jesse

Answer (score 0):

Most modern optimizers take direct value constraints on any variable, i.e.
$$ x_{\min} \leq x \leq x_\max, \quad \text{where } x_\min, x_\max \in \mathbb{R}.$$

If not, why cannot you add two constraints
$x \geq x_\min, x \leq x_\max$ to the model?

Comment: the problem is the constraints on x is

x > 0 or minCapacity < x < maxCapacity. How do you say x can be either zero OR greater than minCapacity?

Comment: @JesseRJ I don't understand your comment, likely a part got deleted by accident?

Comment: yes, i hit enter by mistake

I want to say I have two conflicting constraints

$x = 0$ OR $capacity_\min \leq  x \leq capacity_\max$

Comment: @JesseRJ are you using linear optimization only, or can you have binary variables?

Comment: @JesseRJ Modern optimizers have a special type for that constraint.

Comment: yea I was thinking just now about adding a boolean variable. But I guess I would have to use an integer solver? I am still formulating my objecting function and havent chosen a solver yet

Comment: could you recommend a solver with that type of constraint? I have the matlab optimization toolbox but I dont think this constraint is included. I may be wrong?

Comment: @JesseRJ MATLAB is not a good solver. Maybe `CVXOPT`? http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/examples/index.html There are others that are free. The best paid one is `CPLEX` sold by IBM